# How to set the received messages into single array format

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to display the messages from the receiver , when i checked with the      `console.log(receiveMessages)` i'm getting the data as displayed in the below image. But i want data to be set as  `["hello", "hello amii"]` in a single array , please help me thanks in advance

[image]

```
const [receiveMessages, setReceiveMessages] =  React.useState([]);

socket.on('receive_message', (chatId,msg) =>{
  let newStateMsg = ([...receiveMessages, msg]);
  setReceiveMessages(newStateMsg);
})

useEffect(() => {
 console.log(receiveMessages)
}, [receiveMessages]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use previous state to update state.

Refer to https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

```
socket.on('receive_message', (chatId,msg) =>{
  setReceiveMessages((prevMsg) => [...prevMsg, msg]);
})
```